# How to Run SonarQube Findbugs Analysis for a project with multiple source directories

Tags: maven, sonarqube, findbugs, sonarqube-scan

I have one multimodule maven project where there are source directories apart from 'src' where java file resides.

This is the folder structure

```
folder1
    -pom.xml
```

pom.xml Contains modules defined like this:

```
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
    <module>module4</module>
    <module>module5</module>
    <module>module6</module>
    <module>module7</module>
    <module>module8</module>
    <module>module9</module>
    <module>module10</module>
</modules>
```

Different modules are organized like this:

```
module1
    -src
    -gen

module2
    -src

module3
    -gen

module4

module5
    -src
    -gen
```

So, as you see, there are modules/projects which have either src or gen or both or doesn't have any of it.

When I run findbugs analysis, it picked only java classes from 'src' and skipped 'gen' (Natural as Maven model forces the analyzer to pick from only src)

So, in the Jenkins job configuration, I defined sources explicitly like this:

```
-Dsonar.sources=src,gen
-Dsonar.exclusions=src/test/java/**
```

When I run with this configuration, analysis fails for modules which doesn't have both src and gen. (module2, module3, module4)

So, how do I run the analysis to pick either src or gen or skip that module if either of them is not found ?

Thanks,

Ron

Comment: The question is why do you want to check the 'gen' folder? If it contains like the name indicates only generated source code then it doesn't make sense to scan it. Any possible fixes will be overwritten anyway during the next build. You may define a sonar-project.properties file
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages

Comment: Yes @Lonzak,
'gen' contains the java files (.java) which are generated by some process to maintain the structure of the projects.

But we need to scan both 'src' and 'gen' due to some internal project requirements.

We have more than 50 modules, so defining all these modules in sonar-project.properties and defining their source will be tedious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the SonarQube scanner for Maven, you can't specific properties that only apply to some of the modules using the command line.

In the modules where you want to modify the sources, add in the `pom.xml` a property. For example, in `module5/pom.xml` add:

```
<properties>
  <sonar.sources>src,gen</sonar.sources>
</properties>
```

Comment: Yes Durate, that works. Only modifications I made are 
1. There are 50 modules, so I added this in superpom.
2. Some modules doesn't have either src or gen or neither of it. So, in that case, I had to provide the sources (either src or gen or empty) for those respective modules, else, sonar analysis will fail for those modules